# LaTeX: Font style

Tags: latex

I am a beginner in LaTeX programming. I have a long document (30 pages). The font style in the first two pages is Arial and the font style of the rest of the document is Gramond.
I was wondering how to achieve such thing using LaTex. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Non-programming questions about LaTeX should be asked on [LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use lualatex or xelatex, you can use the `fontspec` package to switch between fonts:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\setmainfont{Arial}
\lipsum

\setmainfont{Garamond}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```